# What consideration would one take when designing a scalable web architecture

Tags: web-architecture

I know that one has to look at the queries for database, because when the database is small queries are not a problem.  But when it becomes larger it could slow down the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some things I would consider...

**Handling Data:**

- Returning as small a dataset as
  possible.  This includes row counts &
  columns.  For example, no `select *
  from table`....
- Data caching strategies

**Web:**

- File Caching.... AKA - HTML, images,
  javascript....
- Put JS at the bottom after DOM loads.
  Increases speed of page load.
- Put CSS at top.
- Session State - be careful with it's
  usage...
- Use CDNs when possible with local
  fallback....
- Minimize the postbacks / http
  requests
- GZip/compress your http
- compress your JS & CSS

**Hardware setup:**

- Load Balancing,proxies...

Comment: Thanks, these web questions always throw me for a loop.  I have taken several clases in programming so web design seems very alien to me.